# Como passar parametros via url para uma aplicação em React?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, react

Tenho uma aplicação em **.Net MVC** onde eu uso a `Session` para armazenar os dados do usuário logado.

Porém dentro dessa dessa aplicação eu tenho uma tela feita em **React** que será acessada **externamente** (ou seja, é um projeto separado), porém preciso passar o ID do usuário logado no **.NET** para o **React**.

Como possa transportar esse dado e recuperar no React por url ?

**Exemplo da URL no .Net:**

```
 <li class="filtro"><a href="https://localhost:44324/@Session["IdUsuarioLogado"]" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt "></i> Operação</a></li>
```

https://localhost/74

**Tela principal que receberá o parametro Operacao.js (React):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Operacao extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

       super(props);


    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }


    componentDidMount() {



    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
            </div>
        );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considerando que você está usando o [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start):

Na configuração da rota, coloca o nome do parâmetro no final do `path` junto com dois pontos(`:`). Ex.: `path="/:id"`

```
<Route exact path="/:id" component={ component} />
```

No componente você pega o parâmetro através do **props**:
`this.props.match.params.id`

obs.: O `id` é um nome opcional, você pode colocar o nome que quiser.

Para mais detalhes, pode consultar a [documentação oficial.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que fazer a rota interna no react

https://medium.com/collabcode/roteamento-no-react-com-os-poderes-do-react-router-v4-fbc191b9937d